# "rilate" + N-finaĵo

Tags: word-usage

Ĉu iu povas klarigi kial en la jena frazo el Tekstaro la vortoj *situacio*, *natura beleco* kaj *artaj konstruaĵoj* aperas sen N-finaĵo post la vorto *rilate*?

> Kvankam Peterburgo ne povas egaliĝi kun nia ĉefurbo rilate la
>   situacio, la natura beleco kaj la artaj konstruaĵoj, tamen ĝi ŝajnis
>   al ni tre interesa kaj, parte, tre bela.

Laŭ vortaroj:

> [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#rilate): En rilato al: *kiel li povas esti tiel blinda **rilate**
>   si**n** mem?; simpatio **rilate** la ideo**n**, por kiu ni laboras; la
>   devoj **rilate** mia**n** familio**n**; okazis unu ŝanĝo, sed nur
>   **rilate** la loko**n** de loĝado; pli bone la homoj ofte ne agis eĉ **rilate** siaj**n** proksimuloj**n**.*
>
> [ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/rilat.html#rilat.0e): rilate al, rilate ...-n  (prepoziciaĵo) Pri, en rilato al,
>   laŭ vidpunkto de, koncerne al: *mi petas vian pardonon pri la malbonaj
>   pensoj, kiujn mi havis **rilate** vi**n**.*

Laŭ [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/rolvortajhoj.html#i-o9b):

> *Rilate al* estas alternativo al simpla *al*, kiam temas pri agmaniero, kiu direktiĝas al io: *Ili ĉiuj kondutis tre serveme rilate
>   al ŝi*. Pli ofte oni uzas *rilate* + N-finaĵon.

Ke la frazo aperas en Tekstaro ne certigas, ĉu ĝi estas erara aŭ ne. Ĝi estas same skribita ĉiuloke, kie mi serĉis interrete, ekz. [ĉi tie](http://i-espero.info/files/elibroj/eo%20-%20langlet,%20valdemar%20-%20vojagximpresoj.pdf) (paĝo 6). Ĉio indikas ke ĝi estas malĝusta, tamen mi ankoraŭ hezitas. Tial, mia demando estas ĉu tiu frazo estas malĝusta, aŭ ĉu eblas iaokaze uzi la vorton *rilate* sekvata de vorto sen N-finaĵo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kiel vi mem trovis, ĉiuj fontoj konsentas. *Rilate -n, rilate al* kaj eĉ *rilate kun* estas ĝustaj. *Rilate* sen akuzativo nek prepozitivo estas simple erara.

Comment: Malgraŭ ke Tekstaro estas bonega rimedo, ĝi tamen estus ankoraŭ pli bona kun malpli da eraroj, precipe por komencantoj ­—sed ne nur. Ankaŭ indas aldoni klarigajn rimarkojn okaze de antaŭnormaj nekutimaĵoj el malnovaj tekstoj, des pli se zamenhofaj.

Comment: Vi tute pravas, sed _Tekstaro_ restas nia plej bona rimedo...